# std::bind of member function with perfect forwarding

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a requirement where I need to bind a member function and pass the arguments with perfect forwarding. This is part of a larger codebase. So, code might not seem relevant. But, I need to fix this in order to move forward.

I am aware of the lambda function solution and that works fine but I don't want to use that and understand 
**why std::bind wrongly assumes that the argument passed to call the binded member function is an argument to that function**

The exact compiler error is this:

> :52:5: error: no matching function for call to object of type
>   'std::_Bind::*(std::_Placeholder<1>, B))(B)>'
>   binder(&a);

But, the expected interpretation should be this:
'std::_Bind::*(B))(B)>'

```
#include <functional>

struct B{
    B(const B&) = delete;
    B(){}
    B(B &&b){}
};

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct A{
    Ret send(Args... argx){
        return Ret();
    }
};

//<---------   Code above this line cannot be changed ----------->

template<class Ret, class ...Args>
void bind_and_forward(Args... args)
{
    using ConnectionType = A<Ret, Args...>;
    auto binder = std::bind(&ConnectionType::send,std::placeholders::_1,std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    ConnectionType a; 
    binder(&a);
    //^---compiler error here
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    bind_and_forward<int>(std::move(b));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really can't use the lambda solution? It's a pity.

Anyway... there are some problems in your code.

If you want use perfect forwarding in `bind_and_forward()` you have to use forwarding references, so you have to add `&&` after `Args` declaring function arguments

```
template <class Ret, class ...Args>
void bind_and_forward (Args && ... args)
// .........................^^
```

and I also suggest to let the compiler deduce the `Args...` types, without explicating them when you call `bind_and_forward()`

```
bind_and_forward<int>(std::move(b));
// ..............^^^ only the return type
```

But the real problem (the problem that cause your compilation error) is that you've deleted the `B` copy constructor

```
struct B{
    B(const B&) = delete; // <-- copy constructor deleted
    B(){}
    B(B &&b){}
};
```

but you receive the arguments (also a `B`) by copy in `A::send()`

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct A{
    Ret send(Args... argx){  // <-- argx are copies
        return Ret();
    }
};
```

You have to choose: you can add a copy constructor in `B`

```
struct B{
    B(const B&) = default; // <-- now you have copy constructor
    B(){}
    B(B &&b){}
};
```

or you can receive `argx` as const references (avoiding copy)

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct A{
    Ret send(Args const & ... argx){ // <-- now by const reference
        return Ret();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @max66 for answering but after reading your response I realized that I missed some restrictions - the struct A and B's code cannot be changed. I have included your suggestions in my code and error message is still the same.

Comment: @Mohit - no idea how to solve your problem if you can't change `A` or `B`; it seems to me that they are incompatible.

Comment: If you can pls explain, I want to know why std::bind is wrongly interpretating the arguments. Specifically the 2nd argument (placeholder::_1) - it is expected to be the object to the send function (1st argument) but actually it is interpreted as the argument to the send function.